# mysql select update user with role

Tags: mysql, linux

Hi i have this tow tables:

*mysql> select username from users where username like '%';*

| username |
| --- |
| admin |
| datacenter |
| network |
| noc-operator |
| storage-operator |
| **tgdwaro2 <---** |
| ws-user |

*mysql> select name from roles where name like '%';*

| name |
| --- |
| Full Control Users |
| Storage Administrator Users |
| Network Administrator Users |
| NOC Operator Users |
| Datacenter Administrator Users |
| Web Service Role |
| **user_role <----------** |

Hier the columns from the tow tables 'roles' and 'users':

*mysql> show columns from roles;*

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int(10) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| name | varchar(50) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| description | text | YES |  | NULL |  |
| parent | int(10) unsigned | YES |  | NULL |  |
| filter | text | YES |  | NULL |  |
| disabled | tinyint(1) | NO |  | 0 |  |

*mysql> show columns from users;*

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int(10) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| username | varchar(50) | NO | UNI | NULL |  |
| password | varchar(100) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| title | varchar(10) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| firstname | varchar(50) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| lastname | varchar(50) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| rolename | varchar(15) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| email | varchar(50) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| treetemplate | longtext | YES |  | NULL |  |
| masterfilter | text | YES |  | NULL |  |
| disabled | tinyint(1) | NO |  | 0 |  |

What i need it's that at the user 'tgdwaro2' from table 'users' i can ad this role 'user_role' from the table 'roles' with a update/select.

Kind Regards and Thank you
Roland

---

Hi Baram I am a beginner in MySql.
Thanks for you Help the Select from you works but the result it's not that wat i need.
It's my fault i have to explane better :-).

I try this:

*(mysql> UPDATE users SET username = (SELECT name from roles where name like 'user_role') WHERE username = 'tgdwaro2';)*

*mysql> select username from users where username like '%';*

| username |
| --- |
| admin |
| datacenter |
| network |
| noc-operator |
| storage-operator |
| **user_role <--befor was tgdwaro2** |
| ws-user |

Wat i need it's that at the user 'tgdwaro2' ad's this role 'user_role'
and not change the user name. Kind Regards and Thank you Roland

Comment: `UPDATE users SET username = (SELECT ...) WHERE username = 'tgdwaro2'`

Comment: If you want to clarify, click the `Edit` button below the question and update it. It's hard to read code in comments.

Comment: `where username like '%'` will match all users, since `%` is a wildcard that matches anything.

Comment: Please show the two tables with all relevant columns, and then what you want the changed table to look like.